# XAML designed fails to load as cannot create a custom object

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a XAML form for use in my application, and I have subclassed the Frame class to create my own, and edited the interface to specify my own class for the content (as I need to access properties on the content for data binding).

The problem comes then in the designer that the compiler says it cannot create an instance  of my control - I've tried to do some designer checks on the offending property bit but that didnt work either.

How can I get the control to display? Works fine at runtime...

XAML:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
 <views:PageFrame Name="Content_MainPage" Frame.NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>                    
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
        public new BaseView Content 
    {
        get
        {
            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                return new BaseView();
            }
            else
            {
                return (BaseView)base.Content;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                base.Content = new BaseView();
                FrameTitle = "design mode";
            }
            else
            {
                base.Content = value;
                FrameTitle = value.Title;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across a similar problem when creating my own Panel class.

Is your PageFrame class defined in the same assembly that your XAML lives in?

I found the only way I could get this to work was to move my "PageFrame" class into a new assembly. From memory I think I even had to build that assembly ahead of time, so that the assembly could be referenced via a file reference (as opposed to a project reference).

I hated this solution, so I hope you find a cleaner one :)

Have you got VS2008 SP1 installed? I had hoped MS would fix this bug. I haven't tried removing my workaround to check...

Comment: I think a 'Hi' is in order too...;-)

Answer (score 0):

Its in the same assembly - and yes I have VS2008 SP1 installed too. Not that removing the above property lets it work fine from a vs point of view, but obviously not from my point of view!

I will give this a go - thanks Antony.

Comment: Yes, I figured so indeed ! Hope all is going well.

Comment: Things are good here. Hope your move to Asia is working out well. Let me know how you get on with your designer problem...